# Good Architecture in Simple C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I'm working on a simple git repo with some C# Console Application Projects that are usually requested in job interviews that I've experienced since I started working with .NET Development.

My issue here is that I have some trouble using good architecture practices. Thanks to that I always end up spending hours trying to picture what would be best in folder and file placements within my solutions.

For example:

[image: job-interview-tests repo folder structure]

This is the structure for that repo.

My first project in this job-interview-tests repository is a console application that checks for prime numbers, and after implementing the logic I noticed that I'd like to create some class that would handle the console texts (e.g.: `Console.WriteLine()`) for title, error and other things.

This is my Program.cs file for the PrimeNumber folder.

```
using System;

namespace PrimeNumber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nBem-vindo ao código de Testagem de Números Primos!");
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
    
                Console.Write("\nInsira um número inteiro natural: ");
                var number = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                var result = CheckPrimeNumber(number) ? $"{number} é um número primo" : $"{number} não é um número primo";

                Console.WriteLine("\n" + result);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opa! O valor inserido não é válido");
                //throw;
            }
            catch(OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Opa! Você inseriu um número negativo ou um número muito grande");
                //throw;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static bool CheckPrimeNumber (uint number)
        {
            bool isZeroOrOne = false, isPrime = false;

            switch (number)
            {
                case 0: 
                case 1:
                    isZeroOrOne = true;
                    isPrime = false; 
                    break;
            }    
                
            if (!isZeroOrOne)
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
                {                
                    if(number % i == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return isPrime;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the subsequent console application projects will use `Console.WriteLine()` commands in order to communicate to the user as well, I want to create a class that adapt these to something like `TextTools.Title(titleName)`, `TextTools.Error(errorMessage)` and so on.

Would this class be placed in a different folder (e.g.: TextTools)? Would it be a static class? Or maybe an abstract one? I'm not really sure about what would be the best way to do this.

I really would like to have some light shed on those kind of doubts so I can start making progress on my own small projects, so thank you in advance if you can leave any piece of advise!

Comment: I think instead of Console application, you should create a class library with various classes and methods in them which accepts parameters and return values. To test the methods you can write unit tests to call those method with various parameters and Assert their results.

Comment: Great, I'll look into class libraries and study them so I can improve this. Thank you @Chetan !

Answer (score 4):

A part of my answer is from the book [Adaptive Code, 2nd Edition](https://www.amazon.ca/Adaptive-Code-coding-patterns-principles/dp/1509302581/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3OX3CSA2ZFWV1&keywords=adaptive%20code&qid=1658888960&sprefix=adaptive%20code%2Caps%2C64&sr=8-1)

[image]

**Visual Studio** IDE will allow you to create a *Solution* that is a set of projects. A project can be of any kind: console, library, winform or WPF etc...

Your project should follow the [N-Tiers](https://medium.com/@hidayatarg/n-tier-layer-architecture-in-c-15b8fe97283c) pattern, where the tier represents a part of your application (here a context that is represented by a project). A tier can be your

- `Presentation Layer` (of type console, winforms etc...)
- `Business Logic Layer` (for business rules -> class library type)
- `Data Access Layer` (to acces your database -> class library type)
- `Business Object Layer` (to represent your business models -> class library type) or even an
- `Utility classes Layer` like in your case ( -> class library type).

You should avoid `static` classes and put your classes in an utility class library for example.

In **Visual Studio**, your project will look something like this, where you can add a project by clicking on `Solution > Add > New Project`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For good hosting I would consider the following almost always:

- Try to separate the application from the hosting
- Try to separate interfaces from the program and the hosting
- Try to minimize the number of dlls required to load
- Try to reduce dependencies in libraries

So in your case the program is hosted in a console app,
use the program.cs class only to ensure your environment is read appropriately and set up any DI stuff, then launch the main application and have the execution of the main application in a separate class, see first pin above.

Then because You may well want to host Your program also in unit tests and perhaps as a service or a WPF, Web or what not. Not only put your main application in a class but put that class in a library, so your Hostings will only have to deal with what is required to feed/ inject into Your application in order to start it.

Consider if parts of Your application will be consumed by different entities. a good example is a DTO (Data Transfer Object) could be used by both submitter and consumer from a service bus e.g. If so put your application in another library/ dll than You application in order not to reference what is not shared from that other place, typically dependencies would otherwise also often travel garbage around where it is not needed.

Do You have a DAL ? (Data access layer) meaning is there a need for attribute annotations or usage in for example EF (Entity Framework) or BSON or what not which You really do not find a need for in the interface part also used other places (reference issue mentioned before, also exposing Your data access method doesn't at least increase security) If so plan for the conversions to and from DTO DAL/ BLE

Do You need a BLE layer? (Business Layer Entity) meaning besides how you store and retrieve data and in what way your send data across the wire, is it worth the tradeoff to model specific a specific class system of objects that more model what Your business people think they're doing to make it easier to model and speak about things in the development process. For Example the OrderManager ... asking on user case what should my order manager be able to do, add new order, query existing orders, by what ... etc.
If it is conceivable that there will be distinctly different things done on your data and even using non-shared-dto structures, consider having your  BL separate from DTO and DAL.

In Your case where it's very restricted problem area and You are in an interview situation, I'll recommend just hinting these thoughts in your single library assembly by making a folder to each and place what you have appropriately.

Actually it is always a good idea not to split up physically before you have a use case for it, in order not to have to load multiple assemblies if fewer can be enough, a rule of thumb is first time you need it from more places than one could be a good time for the physical separation.

Always use .net standard for shared libraries if You can. When working with .net framework applications in Your program topology, keep it to at most .net standard 2.0

I suppose that sums up my generic architecture recommendations,
hope they will save You some headaches not having to retrofit solutions to the reasons behind them when the whys happen :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to have a few projects than its a good idea to create also a dedicated project that wraps the Console and than reference it from your other projects.

a better way would be if you are using .net core is to use the ILogger
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0][1]

Comment: Asker is spending a lot of calories trying to elaborate how wanting to learn about architecture, could you elaborate a bit on why these simple recommendations? I do not disagree on Your points as such, just find the two-liners a bit brief for the intend. Perhaps give a bit to the would-be interview question passing asker?